# ESRI Javascript - Print Task GP Service - Symbology Issue

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, pdf, geoprocessing-service

I am using the ESRI js API, and using a python GP service to run a print task to PDF with custom layouts.  This works great, except when i have any map service enabled in the map.  The layer in the resulting PDF displays jumbo sized points, and I cannot figure out why or what to change.

[image: web_map_example.png]

```
printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(printUrl, { //new instance of print job  
                    async: false //our service is set to syncronous  
                });  
                params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters(); //placeholder for our parameters to put in the script  
                params.map = map; //reference to the active map object  
                function print(){ //action to run when submit is clicked  
                    dojo.style(dijit.byId("statusDialog").closeButtonNode, "display", "none");  

                    document.getElementById("printStatus").innerHTML = " Converting to PDF <img src='loader.gif'>";  

                    var title = dijit.byId("title").get("value") //parameter[2]  

                    var subtitle = dijit.byId("subtitle").get("value") //parameter[3]  

                    var agent = dijit.byId("agent").get("value") //parameter[4]  

                    var legendLayer = new esri.tasks.LegendLayer();  


                    params.template = {  
                        layout: mxdTemplate,  
                        format: 'PDF',  
                        preserveScale: false,  
                        layoutOptions: {  
                            legendLayers: []  
                        }  
                    };   
                    params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference  

                    params.extraParameters = {  
                        Title: title,  
                        Subtitle: subtitle,  
                        Agent: agent  
                    }; //the custom parameters for the python script  
                    printTask.execute(params, printComplete, printError); //run the task, completion triggers 'printComplete' function, any error triggers printError  
                }  

                function printComplete(result){  
                    dojo.style(dijit.byId("statusDialog").closeButtonNode, "display", "block");  
                    console.log(result.url);  
                    document.getElementById("printStatus").innerHTML = "<a href='" + result.url + "' target='_blank'><b>Download PDF<b></a>" //link to the PDF  
                }  

                function printError(error){  
                    dojo.style(dijit.byId("statusDialog").closeButtonNode, "display", "block");  
                    document.getElementById("printStatus").innerHTML = "An unexpected Error has occured <br>( " + error + " )<br> try saving again" //error warning popup  
                }
```

Python GP service

```
import arcpy  
import os  
import uuid  


# Param 0 = INPUT JSON STRING  
# Param 1 = OUTPUT FILE  
# Param 2 = Layout Template  
# Param 3 = Title  
# Param 4 = Subtitle  
# Param 5 = Agent  


# Input WebMap json  
Web_Map_as_JSON = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  

# The template location in the server data store  
templateMxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)   


title = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  


subtitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)  

agent = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)  
# Convert the WebMap to a map document  
result = arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument(Web_Map_as_JSON, templateMxd)  
mxd = result.mapDocument  


# Reference the data frame that contains the webmap  
# Note: ConvertWebMapToMapDocument renames the active dataframe in the template_mxd to "Webmap"  
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, 'Webmap')[0]  


for elem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):  
                if elem.name == "Title":  
                    elem.text = title  

                elif elem.name == "Subtitle":  
                    elem.text = subtitle  

                elif elem.name == "Agent":  
                    elem.text = agent  

# Use the uuid module to generate a GUID as part of the output name  
# This will ensure a unique output name  
output = 'WebMap_{}.pdf'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))  
Output_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, output)  


# Export the WebMap  
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, Output_File)   


# Set the output parameter to be the output file of the server job  
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, Output_File)  


# Clean up - delete the map document reference  
filePath = mxd.filePath  
del mxd, result  
os.remove(filePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is that a reference scale is set for theses map service.
So you can define a corresponding reference scale in environment setting.

For example: `arcpy.env.referenceScale = "25000"`

Please check the document [Reference Scale](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/reference-scale.htm).